# How to use the "debug" module with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, ntvs

I have an NTVS (Node Tools for Visual Studio) project with Typescript.
The following statement doesn't compile:

```
import debug = require('debug')('MyApp');
```

The syntax error being

> (TS) ';' expected

between the the two parenthesis ')('
Is it possible to use "debug" with TypeScript?

Comment: Nothing here worked but finally got it working using this easy approach ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/75757692/1205871

Answer (score 49):

From the [README](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug), debug module is exporting a function that decorates `console.error` with your module name (MyApp). I'm guessing there are other ways, but I use:

```
import Debug from "debug";
const debug = Debug("MyApp");

// then to use
debug("Something happened");
```

And to print everything to the console, run your app with...

```
$ DEBUG=* node MyApp.js
```

Comment: `import * as Debug from "debug";` can be turned into a default import statement `import Debug from "debug";`

Comment: I only got it working by by using the remark by @AndyFaizan. `import * as Debug from "debug"` didn't seem to work (VS Code underlined it in red). Using TypeScript 3.

Comment: Doesn't work with TS4 latest Angular - I give up with npm debug - time to write my own logging func

Answer (score 27):

The answers here did not work for me with more recent versions of Typescript. Here's how I got it working with proper import syntax in Typescript `^3.5.3`:

Install Debug package *and* Typescript types for Debug (types only needed for dev)

```
npm install --save debug
npm install --save-dev @types/debug
```

Then in `.ts` files:

```
import Debug from "debug";
const debug = Debug("AppName");
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: `npm install -D --save-dev @types/debug` is better.

Comment: `-D` and `--save-dev` are the -exact- same parameters, `-D` is just shorthand and I prefer `--save-dev` longhand for exactly this reason; easier to remember.

Comment: I was using scripts to run the node app. I change my start script "export DEBUG=* && nodemon index.ts" and kinda forgot that I have to restart for the changes to take effect. Leaving this here if anyone else runs into the same issue

Comment: Doesn't work with TS4 latest Angular - I give up with npm debug - time to write my own logging func

Answer (score 1):

Remember that TypeScript is a super-set of javascript, so you can still also do this one-liner:

```
const debug = require('debug')('my-app:my-module');
```

Typescript seems to conclude that the `debug` constant here is of type 'any', and you lose all type safety, but with a package as simple as debug is, I think you will be OK...

Personally, I think 2 lines to instantiate debugging in every module is 1 line too many, so I continue to use this one-liner in my .ts files.

P.S. I like to use module tags so I can enable logging in just certain modules with `DEBUG=my-app:my-module,my-app:some-other-module ts-node my-app` or all my modules with `DEBUG=my-app:* ...`

Comment: I should say - 5 years on and I have been converted to Typescript more, and would probably now see this as dirty in a Typescript file... Each to their own...